# How to process DynamoDB stream events with Chalice

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, chalice

I am writing a project where I need to process DynamoDB table inserts and updates in Chalice. I see in Chalice events processing for SNS, SQS, scheduler but not for DynamoDB table. Currently it is not in Chalice, but AWS definitely can do it. What is a recommended workaround?

I do it manually without triggering but it is not as good due to separation of concerns and modularity

I would like to have it something like:

```py
@app.on_dynamodb_table_trigger(table='mytable', event='insert')
def myhandler(event):
    for record in event:
        domyligic()
```

I need my domyligic() function to be called on insert event into table 'mytable'

Answer (score 1):

This feature was added to Chalice on October 2nd, 2020:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/aws-chalice-now-supports-amazon-kinesis-and-amazon-dynamodb-streams/

**requirements.txt**

```
chalice>=1.21
```

**app.py**

```
@app.on_dynamodb_record(stream_arn=os.environ['TABLE_STREAM_ARN'])
def on_table_update(event):
    for record in event:
        process_record(record)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options:

- Contribute to the Chalice project in GitHub to build out the existing proposal to [Add support for Kinesis and DynamoDB stream events](https://github.com/aws/chalice/issues/987).
- Use the Chalice [pure Lambda function](https://chalice.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/purelambda.html) decorator to create your handler. Separately code the logic to configure this Lambda function on a DynamoDB stream using boto3. You can find details in [Using AWS Lambda with Amazon DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-ddb.html).